# Rotated contour pixels

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

```py
    def find_border(self):
        print("Start capturing the border")
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(self.__grayScaledImage, 250, 255, 0)
        contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]

        # There might be multiple are with 255. then you need to find the index of the largest contour
        areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
        max_index = np.argmax(areas)
        border = contours[max_index]
        border = border.reshape(-1, border.shape[2])
        for i, j in border:
            if i >=0 and i < self.__image.shape[0] and j >= 0 and j < self.__image.shape[1]:
                self.__image[i, j] = [255, 0, 0]
        print("Finish capturing the border")

        # cv2.drawContours(self.__image, border, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
        plt.imshow(self.__image)
        plt.show()

        border = border.reshape(-1, border.shape[2])
        return border
```

I have the above code snippets to obtain the border pixels of an image, but when I tried two ways to visualize the border: using `cv2.drawContours` or marking red points on pixels for border pixels.
The drawContours gave me a reasonable output but the point marking method generated a rotated contour.
Later I checked the border pixels and found they are actually the points reflected in the rotated one.
Here I have

```py
self.__grayScaledImage = cv2.cvtColor(self.__image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

I dont know why.
[image: Normal]
[image: Rotated]
[image: Original]

Answer (score 3):

you mixed x and y up somewhere. the contour isn't rotated, it's flipped along the diagonal.

numpy indexing is matrix style. [row, column] or [y,x] if you like

OpenCV gives you (x,y) points, or (column, row)

oh and thanks for using pictures to illustrate the problem. makes things a lot easier than otherwise.